# android admob banner will not display

Tags: android, admob, banner

I have tried everything (admob tutorials, GitHub clones, youtube tutorials, etc.). It will not show on any device (phone or tablet) nor emulator. If anyone could give me some direction I would be grateful.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true" android:orientation="vertical"> <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:background="@drawable/listback1"
    android:alpha="0.8"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        android:text="Food For Thought"
        android:elegantTextHeight="true"
        /> </FrameLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/textsign"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_main"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:title="Choose Your Dining Experiance"/>

<ExpandableListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:divider="@color/orange"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />



    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/ad_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        android:layout_below="@id/expandableListView"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.expandable_layout);



AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.ad_view);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);}
```

gradle

```
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0' 
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:8.4.0'   
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'  
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'  
     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
```

android manifest:

```
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 

     android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|ui
    Mode|s‌​creenSize|smallestScreenSize" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Comment: I forgot the manifest

Comment: <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

Answer (score 0):

Change in your ExpandableListView

```
android:layout_height="0dp"    
android:layout_weight="1"
```